# Empty classes instead of an Enumerations - terrible idea?

Tags: c#, class, enums

I am currently using an enumeration to describe a number of possible operating system platforms.  I have things WIN32, SOLARIS64, LINUX32, but also broader categories like ALLWIN and ALLUNIX.  I have a place in my code where I need to decide if a given Platform falls into the category of another one.  To me, this sounded like inheritance, but obviously enumerations can't inherit from each other.

I then had the thought of turning these Platforms from 1 enumeration into empty classes that inherit from each other.  I feel like this is a terrible idea conceptually and spatially, but not being a master of C# I thought I'd post here looking for some more experienced opinions.  Any thoughts?

This would look something like:

```
public class ALL {};

  public class ALLWIN : ALL {};

    public class WINNT : ALLWIN{};

      public class WIN32 : WINNT{};
```

...
And so on and so forth.

Comment: At least, they shouldn't be ALLCAPS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to stick with enumerations for this. You can do the checking via a bitmask. Something along the lines of:

```
[FlagsAttribute]
enum Systems {
    WinNT = 1,
    Win32 = 2,
    Linux32 = 4,
    Solaris = 8,
    AllWin = WinNT | Win32, // do a bitwise OR of each of the Windows systems
    AllUnix = Linux32 | Solaris // same thing here for Unix systems
}
```

And when you're checking to see if the platform is of a specific system, you'll do so by doing a bitwise AND as in the following code:

```
if (platform & Systems.AllWin > 0) { 
  // this is a Windows system 
}
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: made perfect sense - thanks for explaining and giving the example of later usage.  I knew there was a nicer way than creating like 15 classes that inherit!

Answer (score 6):

Enumerations can't inherit, but they have the concept of flags which accomplishes the same thing you are trying to do:

```
[FlagsAttribute]
enum OSs
{
   WinNT = 1;
   WinNXP = 2;
   AllWIN = WinNT | WinNXP;
}
```

and so on...

Link to [enumerations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx).

Comment: Right. Be sure to put the `[FlagsAttribute]` before the `enum`.

Comment: @jim Thanks! Forgot about that in my flurry of typing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I'm gonna give it to 'cs' because his answer had a bit more info (plus he appears to be a bit newer and could probably use the points).  Thank you though!

Answer (score 1):

One of the key parts of designing a system is to be able to define your domain. This is often the hardest part as well. I would suggest, taking a step back. What is it that you need to define? An operating system? What does an operating system have?
Inheritance is a powerful tool, but this scenario seems to lend itself to a 'has a' relationship, rather than a 'is a' relationship. Instead of having them inherit, perhaps defining an object that has a property. Concider this:

```
    public enum OperatingSystemFamily
    {
        Microsoft,
        linux,
        Mac
    }

    public class OperatingSystem
    {
        public string Name { get { return "WINNT"; } }
        public OperatingSystemFamily Family { get { return OperatingSystemFamily.Microsoft; } }
    }
```

This may be completely off base from what you are trying to accomplish. 
What do you think?

As mentioned elsewhere using enum flags could work as a nice lightweight solution. The only catch is you can never have more than 64 combinations of operating systems and categories.